# JSON parsed to ArrayList. How can I get it to repeat data in onPostExecute for multiple map markers?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask

Title needs a bit more explanation. So I have lots of JSON that I have parsed and put into one ArrayList. The JSON is an Array of shops. The JSONObjects are the shops details, things like name, address, latitude, longitude etc.

Now in my onPostExecute I want to plot these as markers on a map and call the shops information when user clicks on a marker. I've got as far as being able to plot only one shop as a marker. The amount of shops I will have will change constantly over time, right now there are 4.

In my onPostExecute I have following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShopArray> shopArray) {
    super.onPostExecute(shopArray);

    double lat = shopArray.get(0).geo_lat;
    double lng = shopArray.get(0).geo_lng;

    LatLng test = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(test));

}
```

As of now my JSON has 4 shops listed, but it will only plot one on the marker. Is there a way I can call all the latitudes and longitudes and then have all the map markers show? If you need me to post my JSON let me now and I will update my post. This is sort of the final hurdle to get it shown to the user.

Would really appreciate some advice on where I have gone wrong or what can be done better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShopArray> shopArray) {
    super.onPostExecute(shopArray);

    for(ShopArray shopArrayObj : shopArray)
    { 
    double lat = shopArrayObj.geo_lat;
    double lng = shopArrayObj.geo_lng;

    LatLng test = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(test));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! So when I set the Marker onClick as long as I call the data from shopArrayObj I should be fine in getting the rest of the info? All markers are showing up. Accepted answer and +1.

Comment: You need to set the info you need to the marker's labelContent

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm going to try something custom where you handle clicking on the marker to open an alertdialog with all the information. There's a few things on SO about it.